# Tell an InputStream which hits endEncountered to continue instead of closing in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, macos, foundation

I'm trying to continuously read from a file in Swift. The file will have data added continuously to the bottom. I'm trying to use an InputStream to accomplish this:

```
func setup () {
    self.inputStream = InputStream(fileAtPath: "/path/to/file.txt")

    self.inputStream.delegate = self
    self.inputStream.schedule(in: RunLoop.current, forMode: .defaultRunLoopMode)
    self.inputStream.open()
}

func stream (_ aStream : Stream, handle eventCode : Stream.Event)  {
    let inStream = aStream as? InputStream

    switch (eventCode){
    case Stream.Event.openCompleted:
        print("Stream opened")
        break
    case Stream.Event.hasBytesAvailable:
        print("HasBytesAvailable")
        let bufferSize = 1024
        var buffer = Array<UInt8>(repeating: 0, count: bufferSize)

        let bytesRead = inStream?.read(&buffer, maxLength: bufferSize)

        if bytesRead! >= 0 {
            let output = NSString(bytes: &buffer, length: bytesRead!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
            print ("\(output!)")
        }
        break
    case Stream.Event.errorOccurred:
        print("ErrorOccurred")
        break
    case Stream.Event.endEncountered:
        print("EndEncountered")
        break
    default:
        print("unknown")
    }
}
```

However, when it hits the end of the state of the current .txt file, it sends the endEncountered and ceases to read (which makes sense). I just need to figure out a way to tell it to continue. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Couldn't you just create a new file reader, and set the starting index to where the last left off? The stream might also have a "reset" method.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this a different way using pipe.fileHandleForReading.waitForDataInBackgroundAndNotify().

Here is the code I used, if it helps anyone else:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
        self,
        selector: #selector(ViewController.commandOutputNotification(_:)),
        name: NSNotification.Name.NSFileHandleDataAvailable,
        object: nil)

    self.startTasks()
}

func startTasks() {
    self.task = Process()
    self.task!.terminationHandler = self.commandTerminationHandler
    let argumentsString = "tail -n 1 -f /path/to/file/file.log"

    self.task!.launchPath = "/bin/sh"
    self.task!.arguments = ["-c", argumentsString]

    let pipe = Pipe()

    task!.standardOutput = pipe
    task!.standardError = pipe

    pipe.fileHandleForReading.waitForDataInBackgroundAndNotify()

    task!.launch()
}

func commandTerminationHandler(_ task: Process) -> Void {
    // TODO: finish this
}

func commandOutputNotification(_ notification: Notification) {
    let fileHandle = notification.object as! FileHandle
    let data = fileHandle.availableData

    if data.count > 0 {
        processLogData(data:(String.init(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)))
        fileHandle.waitForDataInBackgroundAndNotify()
    }
}

func processLogData(data:String?) {
    // Handle data String here
}
```